# My wifi once worked, but now it doesnt after restart

Tags: networking, 16.04

I just installed 16.04 a few days ago. At first, I installed wifi (compiled from [this link](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E)) and it worked. But later, after a restart, it doesn't. Now I'm using USB tethering from my Android phone.

Here is my system information:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 May 2016 07:52 WIB +0700

Booted last: 09 May 2016 00:00 WIB +0700

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, acpi_osi=, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]

03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8b03 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e069 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0b05:5f04 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s20u1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp0s20u1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.42.82  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6f30:c0e2:7e25:2e5c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29107 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2
          TX packets:22666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31198741 (31.1 MB)  TX bytes:4722629 (4.7 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s20u1  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s20u1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s20u1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s20u1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

   NetworkManager

Running:

root       735     1  0 07:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBridge
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       docker0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       b14bbefc-7288-41e6-a47a-ea9f44ae14e4
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
BRIDGE.SLAVES:                          
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   b14bbefc-7288-41e6-a47a-ea9f44ae14e4 | docker0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20u1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Android
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Android
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20u1' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/enp0s20u1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20u1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       989a6942-e5b6-4b0e-a8dd-0a4c0287b177
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   989a6942-e5b6-4b0e-a8dd-0a4c0287b177 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.82/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.82
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 2979
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1629
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1462757652
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = tom
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6f30:c0e2:7e25:2e5c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SOHO]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SOHO | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SOHO
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TOM.MI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TOM.MI | type=wifi | permissions=user:tom:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TOM.MI
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jakarta (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s20u1  no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s20u1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[   40.992581] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[  476.320392] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 enp0s20u1: renamed from usb0
[  476.349236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u1: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

[image: additional info, might be useful]

Any helps would be very useful. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably received a newer kernel version in an update. After the requested reboot, you must recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/MT7630E
```

Or wherever you cloned the package, if not your desktop

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt76xx
```

Your wireless should again be working.

Comment: You're rock! Thanks so much! It works.. btw, I used `sudo modprobe mt7630e` to make it work.

Comment: Please don't forget to re-compile when an even newer kernel version is installed by Update Manager. In Ubuntu, it is known as *linux-image*. Glad it's working!